# php files newlines missing

Tags: php, ftp, ide, newline

I downloaded php files through ftp. After editing them and uploading them again, I basically always get an error on `line 1` with one of my first actions:

> **Parse error:** syntax error, unexpected '{' in "...etc.

The weird thing is, they work correctly on my local host. They also display fine when I open them in my `IDE` (*jetBrains phpStorm*). However, if I open my files (from local host) in for example *Notepad*, the complete file is on one line.

**Edit: Since my question was marked as a duplicate, i think i need to emphasise this: There is nothing wrong with the code itself. It works perfectly on my local host. I know what unexpected '{' means. The error i entered above is just an example. If the first line was an include(), i would get unexpected include etc. If i copy paste the exact code into a new file, the error is gone.**

I did find out how to fix it for one file. If I simply copy the code in *phpStorm*, create a new file and paste it in there, it works. However, there are around 500 files, so doing this manually would take a lot of time. So my questions are:

1. What causes this kind of behaviour and how can i prevent this in the future.
2. How can i fix this for my current project.

Comment: I have a question to the people who marked this as a duplicate: Did you even read the post? Ofcourse i know what the syntax error means. But i get an error like that in every file, even though there is NOTHING wrong with the code on my local host. The error was just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the type of end-of-line / newline character being inserted by your IDE.

I had a similar problem with Notepad++, and the setting to change was: Edit >> EOL Conversion >> (and in my case I has to set it to Windows Format)

Comment: I Changed them to windows (\r\n\) according to this: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/configuring-line-separators.html However i still have a problem. I also noticed there are a lot of spaces added, sometimes even between variables. So $var will display in notepad as $      var